# Libgdx Trouble render 3d models under 2d sprites

Tags: libgdx

When I use codes like this:
`static void render() { //(spriteBatch draw something) modelBatch.begin(); modelBatch.render(…); modelBatch.end(); spriteBatch.end(); }`
But Why were the spriteBatch displayed under modelBatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sprite batch might have already flushed output before your `end()` call due to changing the drawing context (blend function, shader, projection matrix, etc) of the Sprite Batch, or because the batch was full.

Also, is not safe to interleave batches. You should not begin drawing with one kind of batch without ending the other kind of batch, because each batch makes changes to the OpenGL context that it expects to stay unchanged between its `begin()` and `end()`. For example, your ModelBatch might be enabling depth testing, and SpriteBatch thinks depth testing is turned off because it turned it off in `SpriteBatch.begin()`, but now when it draws in `SpriteBatch.end()` it is drawing with depth testing when it shouldn't.